# 4 wire 220 volt supply > 3 terminal 220 volt plug

Tags: wiring

I need to make a pigtail going from 4 wire (3+ground)220 volt supply to a 3 terminal (2+ground) plug to power my 220 volt welder. How?

Answer (score 5):

First, if your welder has the obsolete NEMA 10 type plug (slanted hot blades, neutral **and no ground**), cut it off and smash it.  *It was NOT put there by the manufacturer, some imbecile did that.*  Those plugs have been illegal since before the Apollo missions for everything but dryers and ranges.  (For those banned in 1996).  If you cut the plug off, feel free to install the appropriate 4-prong plug - just don't hook up neutral on the plug.

Now if your welder has *the correct* NEMA 6-30 or 6-50 type plug, then all you need is a short adapter cable.

- Make it with 3-wire **cordage** (e.g. SO, SW, SJOW, SJOOW etc.) which is highly flexible and made for appliance cords. Any competent electrical supply will have that.
- On the plug end, install a NEMA 14-30 or 14-50 PLUG to match your available socket.  Don't hook anything to the neutral pin.
- On the socket end, install a NEMA 6-30 or 6-50 SOCKET of the same size (amps) as the plug.

The socket amps (the last number) need to match each other and also the wire size.  10 AWG wire for 30A, 6 AWG for 50A.

You can also just buy this as a pre-assembled cable. Make sure it is UL Listed. (shouldn't be a problem, your arrangement is perfectly legal).

Comment: That is true. How about you explain it to me. Please say where to attach each wire on each end of pigtail

Comment: @SiSouthall Green to ground, black to L1, red or white to L2. I may have jumped the gun by not asking what your connectors actually are. Can you add photos?

Comment: Don’t know how. Socket end of pigtail (where welder plugs in)is two parallel straight up and down slots (1 larger than other & 1 round. Inside socket has places for 2 hots & 1 neutral  Plug end of pigtail (where it plugs into generator) is 4 prong in round configuration with one L-shaped foot. Inside plug is place for 2 hots, 1 neutral & 1ground  What do I do with ground wire in socket end of pigtail that only has places for 3wires

Comment: @SiSouthall Ground gets connected through. Neutral terminal is ignored.  Sounds like a NEMA 6-50 on the welder (good), and NEMA 14-30 on the wall socket. Normally wiring that would be illegal due to 30 vs 50, but welders have *really weird rules*.

Comment: Ground gets connected through to what? To round leg in socket end? Then what do I do with neutral wire coming from plug end? There’s no place for it if I connected ground to round leg of socket

Comment: Sorry to be so dull but I still have a 4th wire that I need to know what to do with on a 3 terminal set up in socket end of pigtail?

Comment: So ground is connected through to round leg of socket end & no nuetral wire is used on nuetral terminal of plug end of pigtail? Correct?

Comment: @SiSouthall  not sure why your cable has a neutral wire.  Doesn't need one. Cut it off at both ends of the stripped sheath area so it can't get near a contact.

Comment: Thank you all. Got it done